# How do i change the content of a div when the browser is reduced or increased

Tags: html, css, width

I have a dilemma I've been trying to sort.

I have a website with a width that shrinks depending on the browser size. But the problem is that it can only go as low as 1000px as anything lower than that will mean the menu will overlap the logo and it does not look pretty.

One thing I could do is to change the design all together but that will take time as I've spent countless hours on this current design.

I'm actually designing for iPad and mobile users in mind and basically I want the menu items to reduce in number depending on the space available.

For example, if I have the following menu items (Home, about, services, products, faq, contact us), when it encounters a smaller width, it should probably get rid of products, faq and contact us and put a menu icon that users can click on and see the remaining menu items.

Below is what I have currently:

```
 <div id="menu">
     <a href=index.php>Home</a>
     <a href=about.php>About</a>
     <a href=services.php>Services</a>
     <a href=products.php>products</a>
     <a href=faq.php>FAQ</a>
     <a href=contact.php>Contact</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using media queries. This Mozilla Developer article will help you a lot, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries. It basically works by showing certain content under conditions that you set. For example if the screen is smaller than 1000px show one div and if it's larger show another. If you need additional support setting this up I'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to keep it simple, you can use css media queries, this should add `display:none;` to class `hide-from-menu` when browser is below `1000px` resolution

css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){ /* or some else breakpoint*/ 
  .hide-from-menu{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
 <div id="menu">
 <a href="index.php">Home</a>
 <a href="about.php">About</a>
 <a href="services.php">Services</a>
 <a class="hide-from-menu" href="products.php">products</a>
 <a class="hide-from-menu" href="faq.php">FAQ</a>
 <a class="hide-from-menu" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: I think this is perfect. Thanks. Is there a way i could add an additional menu item when the others are removed?

Comment: of course, just make another class that have `display:none;` by default and show it in query with `display:block;`(or any other display that you use)

Comment: I actually thought of this and actually tried it but it didn't work. I think i'm getting something wrong.